# how to run a JAR file as a Java Progam specifically http://iapg.jade-hs.de/personen/brinkhoff/generator/

Tags: java, jar

I need to run a specific class from this project
iapg.jade-hs.de/personen/brinkhoff/generator/

The generator's jar file is located in here:
iapg.jade-hs.de/personen/brinkhoff/generator/RunTime21.zip

There is not much documentation on the running part.  It is mainly assumed that the user is advance enough to know how to do this.

The jar file contains the following:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
spatial/BasicSpatialQuery.class
drawables/DrawableObjects.class
spatialdb/DefaultGeometryFactory.class
spatial/LayerWindowQuery.class
util/Num.class
...
...
...
generator2/ExternalObject.class
generator2/DefaultDataGenerator.class
drawables/DrawableCircle.class
spatial/ExactMatchQuery.class
drawables/DrawableObject.class
generator2/ConstantObjectGenerator.class
drawables/DrawableSpatialSearchTreeObject.class
```

I need to run generator2/DefaultDataGenerator with a specific parameter which is included with the generator.

The Manifest file has just this in it:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

There is a .bat file (assuming it is provided for Windows) which has the following:

```
java -classpath .;generator21.jar generator2.DefaultDataGenerator propOL.txt
```

Problem: I am at a loss on how to actually run the generator2/DefaultDataGenerator as a Java program (NOT applet)

I have tried:

1) `java -jar generator21.jar` which gives me

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from...
```

2) `java -classpath . ; ./generator21.jar generator2.DefaultDataGenerator propOL.txt`
which gives me the same error namely

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from /home/username/generator/generator21.jar
```

3) have tried to edit the Manifest file as per http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html and adding one extra line in there which reads:

```
Main-Class: generator2.DefaultDataGenerator
```

mainly since the source file for generator2.DefaultDataGenerator package from the sources which are to be found in here: iapg.jade-hs.de/personen/brinkhoff/generator/CompleteSource21.zip

show the following:

```
    /**
     * main entrypoint - starts the part when it is run as an application
     * @param args args[0] = name of the property file
     */
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
            if ((args.length > 0) && (args[0] != null))
                    propFilename = makeAbsolute(args[0]);
            main ("generator2.DefaultDataGenerator");
```

However, when I edited the Manifest file and I tried to run it via java -jar jarfile.jar
I got the following error:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   
     generator2/DefaultDataGenerator Caused by:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: generator2.DefaultDataGenerator
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    Could not find the main class: generator2.DefaultDataGenerator. 
    Program will exit
```

Please assist.

Thank you

Comment: This was the problem:  I need to specify the directory of where the jar was not the jar itself.

java -classpath ../generator/ generator2.DefaultDataGenerator

made it run

Comment: Please, add this as answer and accept it, so the question will be closed.

Comment: I would recommend fixing the manifest so you can run it with `java -jar <jar_file>` and not require `-classpath` on the command line to run it.

Answer (score 0):

This was the problem: I need to specify the directory of where the jar was not the jar itself. java -classpath ../generator/ generator2.DefaultDataGenerator made it run